# rails date_select, select year only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I have a form which allows user to select date, in the view i have it so the user only selects the year, but when the date is saved, it saves todays day and month along with it? all I want it to display is the year, which the user selects, this is my code:

```
<%= f.date_select :finishdate, :order => [:year] %><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
<%= f.select_year :finishdate, :order => [:year] %><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to show only the year value in the form and store it in the database without the month and day, then you can have an integer field and only show the year value as follows:

```
<%= f.select :finishdate,Date.today.year-10 .. Date.today.year+10 %>
```

Comment: I have come across this answer after it _was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content_. Please don't just "dump" code, but rather provide an explanation of what the code does and why it should work.

Answer (score 1):

What is the end result that you'd like to work with? If it is only the year, you'll probably not want to use the `date_select` as that, I believe, will return a `DateTime` instance and not just the year.

If you do need just the year, you can look into other helpers like `select_year`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f.date_select :date_field, { discard_month: true, ... }`

You can find the full documentation for the `date_select` helper here:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select